# Hibernate setting an object conditionally for saveOrUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to conditionally set a value when using saveOrUpdate method in hibernate? My scenario is I need to set status as NEW when a row is inserted or when updated it should be set as MODIFIED. Am trying to use the saveOrUpdate method and get this done. Hence is it possible to set status in this way?

Sorry I didnt post the code earlier..

below is the code snippet

```
SessionFactory sessionfactory1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory1();
    Session session = sessionfactory1.openSession();
    Transaction transaction1 = session.beginTransaction();
    SearchFileMasterDO oSearchFileMasterDO = new SearchFileMasterDO();
    oSearchFileMasterDO.setId("some unique name");//identifier
    oSearchFileMasterDO.setText("some value");
    oSearchFileMasterDO.setStatus("NEW"); //if an update happens it needs to be set as "MODIFIED"
    session.saveOrUpdate(oSearchFileMasterDO);
    transaction1.commit();
    session.close();
```

Basically I need to know if there is a way to change the status based on the scenario. Is it possible to do that directly with a saveOrUpdate call?

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried. It should be simple to do so if you fetch the object and check the status before calling saveOrUpdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to check the existence of data you are trying to commit then you can set the flag accordingly. So you can do following:

1. If you are having any auto generated column and it is set manually by you then it will be null in bean for new data.
2. If you are having auto generated key that is set by DB using some sequence generator then also the field will be null.
3. In case data is existing in DB then you would be pulling the data from DB first and then update it before persisting it to DB.
4. In case you do not have auto generated key step 3 can help in that case too.

So ablve should help you in identifying if status is NEW or MODIFIED. This is actually like marking data dirty manually before you commit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By pulling the data do you mean I have to fetch using a query,check and update again? When we use saveOrUpdate there is no need for us to write a separate query to check right?I wanted to know if there is any facility in hibernate which could handle such scenario wherein we can use the same method and set the DO values conditionally

Comment: Yes you need to query with saveOrUpdate. If you need to insert (which you need to check by checking Identifier for data) better to use save explicitly and not saveOrUpdate as in that case you will always create new object to persist.